# How to run a Python project from GitHub to VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to run this [project](https://github.com/MubertAI/Mubert-Text-to-Music) from Github to VSCode, I have cloned the repository, installed Python from the Microsoft app store, but I still get some error like this 1[image: like this]

and 2 [image]

and warnings like this
[image]

and im cannot run the project. Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The project you have installed seems to use [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

After reading the above, I recommend you install all imported modules

EX:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(arr)
print(type(arr))
```

You would input `pip install numpy` in order to install the module.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the entire code and install all the imported packages, for example: `numpy` and others using `pip install`.